# Should I use multiple index method if indexed fields are also foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

After adding foreign keys mysql forced to index the keys which indexed before with multiple index method. I use InnoDB.

Here is a structure of my table:

`id`, `company_id`, `student_id` ...

`company_id` and `student_id` had been indexed using:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `multiple_index` (`company_id`,`student_id`)
```

Why I use multiple index column? Because, the most time my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE company_id = 1 AND student_id = 3
```

Sometime i just fetch columns by student_id:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE student_id = 3
```

After adding foreign keys for `company_id` and `student_id` mysql indexed both of them separately. So, now I have multiple and separately indexed fields.

My question is should I drop the multiple indexed keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If the same student belongs to many companies, no, don't drop it. When querying for `company_id = 1 AND student_id = 3`, the optimizer has to pick one index, and after that, it will either have to check multiple students or multiple companies.

My gut tells me this won't be the case, though; students won't be associated with more than ~10 companies, so scanning over the index a bit won't be a big deal. That said, this is a lot more brittle than having the index on both columns. In that case, the optimizer knows what the right thing to do is, here. When it has two indices to pick from, it might not, and it might not in the future, so you should `FORCE INDEX` to make sure it uses the student_id index.

The other thing to consider is how this table is used. If it's rarely written to but read frequently, there's not much of a penalty beyond space for the extra index.

TL;DR: the index is not redundant. Whether or not you should keep it is complicated.

Comment: Got it! I used multiple index, just because it is a big data. I was thinking that using multiple index, i could fetch student's information faster.